# Access Rights required for Session database

Tags: sql-database, session-state, shared-session

I configured private and shared session using `SQL Provider`, following [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/scaling-and-configuring-session-state.html) link After I deployed the `Sitecore.Sessions.dacpac` file, I tried to create a user for the database but it was failing with the error

```
USE [MyProject_Sessions]
GO

CREATE USER [sessionsuser] WITH PASSWORD='password@123', DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

[image]

So I created a login assigned db_datareader and db_datawriter like in other users such as master user but the login did not work. Currently, I'm using 'sa'. If I want to create a separate login for this DB, what all roles are required.

**Version:** `Sitecore 9.2 Initial`, `Microsoft SQL Server 2017`

Comment: can you share the SQL script you are using to create?

Comment: @GopikrishnaGujjula I updated the question with the query, please check

Answer (score 2):

From the error it seems that your database server is not configured with Contained Authentication.

Please execute below script on your server

> sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;
>   GO
>   RECONFIGURE;
>   GO

Comment: This I tried already but did not work.  I found below  in sitecore setup package and was able to create a new user 
Use [PlaceholderForDB]
GO

alter database [PlaceholderForDB] 
set containment = partial
GO

CREATE USER [PlaceHolderForUser] WITH PASSWORD = 'PlaceHolderForPassword';
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', [PlaceHolderForUser];
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', [PlaceHolderForUser];
GO

GRANT EXECUTE TO [PlaceHolderForUser];
GO

Comment: Can you please update the question with SQL server version you are using?

Comment: Updated with sql version